# Android: Compass too far in map

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, mylocationoverlay

In Android I use the [MyLocationOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MyLocationOverlay) to enable the Compass, but the problem is, that on a HTC Wildfire, the compass is too far into the screen (see screenshot).

[image]

On a larger screen, for example the Galaxy S3, the compass is exactly in the top left corner.

Question: How can I put this compass on the top left corner of the map?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you install some compass application on both phones and see the compass is actually working fine on the phone?